# How to update systemjs to look in paths?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-local-storage

According to this issue: https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage/issues/50 to use localstorage with angular-cli I need to update systemjs to look in paths:

- node_modules/angular2-localstorage/dist/LocalStorageEmitter.js
- node_modules/angular2-localstorage/dist/WebStorage.js

I've tried like this, but it didn't work

```
System.config({
  paths: {
   "LocalStorageEmitter": './node_modules/angular2-localstorage/dist/LocalStorageEmitter.js',
   "WebStorage": './node_modules/angular2-localstorage/dist/WebStorage.js'
 }
});
```

How to do it in correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do this following way:

```
System.config({

map: {
"LocalStorageEmitter" : "node_modules/angular2-localstorage/dist",
"WebStorage": "node_modules/angular2-localstorage/dist"
},

packages: {
"LocalStorageEmitter": {main : "LocalStorageEmitter.js", defaultExtension: "js" },
"WebStorage": {main: "WebStorage.js", defaultExtension: "js"
}

});
```

Now you can do

```
import {__PACKAGE_NAME__} from 'LocalStorageEmitter';
import {__PACKAGE_NAME__} from 'WebStorage';
```

in one of your typescript file.